# Google Drive API Get VideoMediaMetadata Error

Tags: c#, video, google-drive-api, metadata

I wonder why it gives me an exception of invalid parameter when i request the details of a file which is a video and want to get its resolution. I use:

```
var f = service.Files.Get(id);
f.Fields = "VideoMediaMetadata.Height";
var result = f.Execute();
```

I tried many different ways: "VideoMediaMetadata" without ".Height", "VideoMediaMetadata(height, width)", "VideoMediaMetadata/Height" etc. but nothing worked. When i do this for example:

```
f.Fields = "id, name, size";
```

It works fine.

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

It gives off an invalid parameter because GET was expecting a VideoMediaMetadata [object resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource) but you instead tried to access the int values. I suggest passing VideoMediaMetadata as your parameter first and execute the request. After that, parse the response body for the 'height' and 'width' int property.

So using your code above:

```
f.Fields = "VideoMediaMetadata";
```